# incomplete mahapps.metro dialogs

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I' using mahapps.metro with custom accent. I'm changing accent through code when application starts.
Since when I have done that dialogs are not showing up properly.

[image]

I couldn't figure out what's going wrong.
My App.xaml is,

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Indigo.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and in code,

```
Uri objUri = new Uri("Assets/CustomAccent.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Accent acc = new Accent("CustomAccent", objUri);
ThemeManager.ChangeTheme(App.Current, acc, Theme.Light);
```

In my custom accent, I'm just changing the colors, nothing else. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a custom accent you must add it to the `ThemeManager` before you can use it (`MahApps.Metro` [v1.0.0](http://mahapps.com/news/)).

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // add custom accent and theme resource dictionaries
        ThemeManager.AddAccent("CustomAccent1", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahAppsMetroThemesSample;component/CustomAccents/CustomAccent1.xaml"));

        // get the theme from the current application
        var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);

        // now use the custom accent
        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                    ThemeManager.GetAccent("CustomAccent1"),
                                    theme.Item1);

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.